# read MAC address of machine from Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, macos, air, adobe

i want to read MAC address of machine from Adobe AIR. I am using flex 3 and AIR 2.

how can i do this

the main purpose is i want to install that product in only one machine

Comment: Well, the limiting factor of allowing an application to be installed when it depends on a MAC address is rather pointless.
Anyone with a flash decompiler and mac spoofer could easily find and circumvent this "safeguard"

Answer (score 6):

```
var ni:NetworkInfo = NetworkInfo.networkInfo;
var interfaceVector:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = ni.findInterfaces();
```

Taken from the Network Info sample in the desktop version of [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you cannot do it with Flex/AIR alone - you can however use the [NativeProcess](http://mchristoff.com/2009/12/using-the-air-2-0-nativeprocess-api-to-control-mplayer/) API to communicate with a Java/C program that can do this for you.

<sub>If you want to limit your application to just one machine, why don't you just install it manually without giving away the setup file - is it a remote machine? Even in that case you should be able to do a remote installation, right?</sub>

Comment: thnx very much amar ghosh....the product will be subscribed by 10 users and can be installed only on 10 machines...so i m planning to track the mac address

Comment: @mendieta So you plan to get their MAC addresses in advance and hardcode them?

Comment: @mendieta is this a web based application? In that case, you can assign unique identifiers to your users and do a one time mapping of those id's with their IP addresses - just deny service if the request comes from a different id/ip combination.

Answer (score 0):

The answer "track the combination of IP address and user ID" won't satisfy my (very similar) needs.  If the (laptop) computer is moved across WiFi domains, its IP address will change.  If the computer is on a commerical IP provider, the IP address can often change without warning or notice.

My users don't want to deal with such problems.  They don't even want to know that these problems exist!

The binding of MAC address and user ID can be done at installation time.  It's not perfect, but it's pretty good.

Of course what we need is an implementation of public-private key...

Oz