# ActionScript class to get unique system id

Tags: actionscript-3, uniqueidentifier, source-code-protection

Is there a way to get a unique system id using ActionScript?

I found this answer but it appear to be all C++ 
[get unique machine id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004666/get-unique-machine-id)

Anyway, I am looking for a deterrent for copying our Flash App.  It will be installed on a select number of kiosk in stores.  Anything outside of that we want the client to come back to us.

It doesn't have to be rock solid just an annoyance.

My thinking is that we would define a list of system IDs in code and just do  a simple compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the machine's MAC address if you are using AIR:
[read MAC address of machine from Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362479/read-mac-address-of-machine-from-adobe-air)

Also:
[NetworkInterface docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInterface.html)